# Custom View поведение onDraw в зависимости от выбора атрибутов в разметке

Tags: android, view, customview, android-customview

Необходимо реализовать собственное `View`, которое будет рисовать на экране круг, квадрат или треугольник. Фигура должна выбираться из файла разметки. Вот атрибуты из файла разметки:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="PainView">
    <attr name="figure" format="enum">
        <enum name="circle" value = "0"/>
        <enum name="square" value = "1"/>
        <enum name="triangle" value = "2"/>
        <enum name="line" value = "3"/>
     </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Вот разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

<com.example.Widgets.PainView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:figure="square"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот CustomView:

```
public class PainView extends View {
private Paint mPaint = null;
private int cellSize = 30;

public PainView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.initView();
}

public PainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.initView();

    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PainView);

    Integer circle = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.PainView_figure, 0);
    Integer square = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.PainView_figure, 1);
    Integer triangle = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.PainView_figure, 2);

    attributes.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    int h = this.getHeight();
    int w = this.getWidth();

    int radius = (h / cellSize) + 1;
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, radius, mPaint);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 0, 0, mPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(triangle(), mPaint);



}

private void initView(){
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

private Path triangle(){
    Point a = new Point(0, 100);
    Point b = new Point(50, 0);
    Point c = new Point(100, 100);

    Path triangle = new Path();
    triangle.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    triangle.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
    triangle.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
    triangle.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
    triangle.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
    triangle.close();

    return triangle;
}
}
```

Не могу придумать как передать выбор разметки из конструктора в метод `onDraw`.

Comment: есть такие поля класса, переменные, доступные во всех методах класса

Comment: Запутался просто, когда аттрибуты извлекал в конструкторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых лучше извлекать атрибуты по [гайдлайну Android](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). И сразу отвечая на ваш вопрос:

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.PainView,
        0, 0);

   try {
       shape = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PainView_figure, 0);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
```

Переменную `shape` нужно сделать полем простого типа `int`.